# Minecraft weapons shotgun

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

is there a way to easy make shotgun in vanilla minecraft using only command blocks and redstone? I want to recreate somehow mineplex paintball shotgun, but I got stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to use a resource pack or not?

Comment: It would be better if not, but if it is nessesery then yes

Comment: Mineplex uses a plugin, just in case you didn't know

Comment: I know but I am trying to recreate Mineplex in vanilla with command blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you create a scoreboard that ticks up 1 every time you right click with golden horse armor in their hand:

> /scoreboard objectives add gunclick stat.useItem.minecraft.golden_horse_armor

then make a compararator with this command on the output:

> /scoreboard players set @a gunclick 0

Whenever someone right clicks with golden horse armor in their hand, Just for a second, the score will tick to 1.

Now you can harness this power my making a command block clock:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1zd05v/how_to_make_a_fast_setblock_clock_in_minecraft/

and then set the output to a command block that tests for anyone with that tick of 1:

> /tesfor @a[score_gunclick_min=1]

Then you need to put a comparator in front of that and a repeater in front of that. Then, line redstone to a command block that will summon a firework rocket in front of the player and in the direction the player is looking. Unfortunately i don't know how to do that along with how to set up the killing using the gun. So i hope this helps!